# adding JSON object to JSON array at runtime issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

simply I want to get value of a key at JSON object but at run time, 
this work at design time like this.

```
 var studentsData = [
            { "studentName": "Elen", "Birthyear": 1981 }
            , { "studentName": "Stev", "Birthyear": 1987 }];
console.log(studentsData[0].studentName); // print Elen
```

**But** if push object to the array at runtime like this

```
var studentsData = [];
var jsonObj={ "studentName": "Elen", "Birthyear": 1981 };  //because i intend to get the object data at runtime
studentsData.push(jsonObj);
console.log(studentsData[0].studentName);
```

by this way it give me error :**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'studentName' of undefined**
please help, THANK YOU

Sorry by mistake i put different array variable from another code, 
but it seems that My real problem from the start was the same non solved this problem :-
     [How do I assign a variable from localForage as I do in localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388850/how-do-i-assign-a-variable-from-localforage-as-i-do-in-localstorage)

Comment: You are trying to read `populationData` and not `studentsData`?

Comment: You need to clarify what language you are writing in. and add that in the tag as well.

Comment: You have missed something. What is `populationData` in the first and second case? Since it works in case #1, show where and how declare it.

Comment: You've tagged your post "local-storage", but do not mention local storage. Does this question have something to do with local storage? Does it have something to do with JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to read `studentsData` instead of `populationData`.

**working demo :**

using `for in` loop :

```js
 var studentsData = [
            { "studentName": "Elen", "Birthyear": 1981 }
            , { "studentName": "Stev", "Birthyear": 1987 }];

for (var i in studentsData) {
  console.log(studentsData[i].studentName);
}
```

using Array `map()` function :

```js
 var studentsData = [
            { "studentName": "Elen", "Birthyear": 1981 }
            , { "studentName": "Stev", "Birthyear": 1987 }];

var result = studentsData.map(function(elem) {
  return elem.studentName;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing wrong variable.
use `studentsData` instead:

```
var studentsData = [];
var jsonObj={ "studentName": "Elen", "Birthyear": 1981 };  //because i intend to get the object data at runtime
studentsData.push(jsonObj);
console.log(studentsData[0].studentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

> console.log(studentsData[0].studentName);

Since you are adding the json object to *studentsData* array.