# What's the best way to retrieve items with localforage and store their values on a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, localforage

I want to retrieve values with localforage and store them in a dictionary.

I've been trying this:

```
localforage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
baz = {
    foo: await localforage.getItem('foo')
}
console.log(baz.foo);
```

but it keeps giving me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (at test.js:3:13)` marking `localforage.getItem('foo')` on Line 3

When I enter this on console, it works as expected and prints `bar`

Comment: Are you running it in an async function?

Comment: @Tanay I am not. I may be wrong, but as far as I'm aware, `localforage.getItem()` returns a `Promise` so I have to use `await` to retrieve its value. I tested it out without `await` and it gave me `Promise {<pending>}`

Comment: I know `localforage.getItem()` returns a Promise and to use `await` you have to run the expression in an async function

Comment: @BGPHiJACK According to them, "localForage uses aync storage". (https://github.com/localForage/localForage)

Comment: @Tanay I'm currently referring to their docs (https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-getitem) and I can't see anything regarding the use of async function. Can you provide an example or reference so that I may get a better idea on what you are trying to convey?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the getItem in an async function to use await. Also, `localforage.setItem` returns a Promise, so you should use await to make it synchronous

```js
async function doWork() {
   await localforage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
   baz = {
       foo: await localforage.getItem('foo')
   }
   console.log(baz.foo);
}
doWork()
```

Comment: That did the work. Thank you. It is quite confusing how answers on other related questions imply that you could just use `await` directly when working with localForage. Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47034912/19023238